# Could we vertically center the score text inside their frame box?

Tags: feature-request, design

I've noticed the new frame boxes around the scores:

[image]

I like them, just, could they have the text vertically centered? Now they are *shifted* one pixel to top in my browser (Chrome 40.0.2214.115 on Windows). See how this shift by 1 pixel down changes the whole world:

[image]

---

<sup>If that's the part of a preparation for the new profile page, let me know and I'll burn this post...</sup>