# Let the upvotes be green!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page

I already [posted this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250450) on MSE in the thread about the new profile page which is only out on Meta.SE and though that it relates only to Meta.SE...

But it seems to affect also SO.

So, please return green to the upvotes in the summary tab (redesign didn't affect accepts however):

> [image]

**Edit:** This problem doesn't seem to be really narrow, I also noticed this problem on some other SE sites:

- [UX](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-experience)
- [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com)
- [Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)
- [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)
- [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com)

So this request pertains to those above sites too.

Comment: I actually *like* the new design. It gives me a far quicker idea of how many accepts I have, which, frankly, are far more important to me than the 20 +10s I can get in a day.

Comment: @Mart not everyone is skeeting every day :)

Comment: I think it is not encouraging when upvotes are grey and *neutral* and downvotes are red :/

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: What if the background is kept white for upvotes and downvotes, and just the numbers were green for upvotes, and red for downvotes? And keeping the green background for accepted answers, and maybe red background for deleted ones?

Comment: I survive solely on the sight of green boxes that read *+10*, *+20*, ..

Comment: What does "skeeting" mean in this context? (I'm not Googling it because of the other meaning.)

Comment: @BSMP http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: @m-z Good googley moogley! On topic, I agree with Martijn that a visual distinction between accepted answers and just up votes is useful but I don't have a strong opinion on how that's accomplished. Guillermo's suggestion seems like it would work.

Comment: Please be wary of those that may have colorblindness and have a harder time distinguishing between shades of red and green.  Perhaps we can add a color blind mode for all stackexchange sites.

Comment: @bsmp oh heavens! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts#comment16578_9134 - certainly you're this guy.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: Some care needs to be taken, but color-blindness doesn't mean that things of the affected colors disappear. They're still visible: just in a shade of grey. You need to make sure that the shade of the color is dark enough that it's visible without the hue information, but other than that there's no issues.

Comment: @nicael, Haha no, I've only gone under this name on Stack Overflow. But now I know and knowing is half the battle.

Comment: The upvotes appear white and gold to me.

Comment: @Dav However they are blue and black. Look closely.

Comment: I thought the green ones were the `Accepted Answer` +15s.

Comment: If we are at, could we also [center the text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287176/960757) inside?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh. Just look. Can I believe my eyes? Is it green now?

[image]

Comment: Clearly black and blue.

Comment: Consider the CSS an old house that was once up to builder's code, but over the years has grown outdated. When you go in to replace the wood paneling with drywall, you realize that the outlets need to be rewired. As you're doing that you realize the circuit breakers need replace and things aren't properly grounded. But when you're done with everything, it's so worth it because the updates allow for future growth.

Comment: Cool; it's green! And vertically mis-centered :(

Comment: @Tlama Not my fault :D

Comment: I know. I'm just trying to get more attention to that issue through your *thread* (parasitise :p) Mine was seen 65 times whilst yours 2992 times.